# Match exact color between Node and what is being rendered

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine

You know how you get a color without any shading when plugging in a color output into a shader socket? Is there a way to make sure that exact color is being rendered?
I'm working with a strict color scheme and want to match it exactly.
I'd really prefer it to work with EEVEE since it has the Shading2RGB node.

Answer (score 1):

Emission shader with strength of 1 should output the exact color you connect to the color input. Thought volumetrics would affect the resulting color ("overlaying" over it).

Comment: Getting Blender to diplay a straight color without any shading is easy - that's not what I was thinking about. The problem is that Blender applies a lot of color transforms - which results in me not getting the exact color I want